# Given a list of required colums (stored table variable), check a physical table for any null values in the list of required field set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table variable that indicates the set required fields based on contact type.

```
ContactTypeID   FieldID  ColumnName   FieldName
1               1        FirstName    First Name
1               2        LastName     Last Name
1               3        HomePhone    Home Phone
2               1        FirstName    First Name
2               2        LastName     Last Name
2               3        HomePhone    Home Phone      
2               4        Address      Home Address
2               5        Email        Email Address
```

I have a physical table with the following structure

```
ContactID  ContactTypeID  FirstName  LastName  HomePhone     Address  Email
1          1              Mary       Smith     Null          Null     Null
2          1              Jim        Smith     999-999-9999  Null     Null
3          2              Steve      Jones     Null          Null     Null
```

I want to the results to display the `ContactID`s that have `null` values in any of the required required field table variable.

So based on the information above, I would expect `ContactID`s of  1 and 3

I would prefer not to use cursor or dynamic SQL unless there is no other way.

Comment: You cannot do this without dynamic SQL.

Comment: looking for all options, so dynamic or while loop may be acceptable, just would like the most efficient way of performing the check

Comment: I think actually, it could be possible if you unpivot your second table and use a left join to the required fields table to figure out if the contactid has all of its required columns. Unpivoting null values would not result in any rows generated in the unpivoted table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the types are compatible (say all strings), I would unpivot the entire table using `apply` and then compare and aggregation:

```
select distinct ContactId
from physical p cross apply
     (values ('FirstName', FirstName),
             ('LastName', LastName),
             ('HomePhone', HomePhone),
             ('Address', Address),
             ('Email', Email)
     ) v(col, value) join
     required r
     on v.contactTypeId = p.contactTypeId and
        v.col = r.ColumnName
where v.value is null;
```

Comment: This seems to return the contact ids 1,2 and 3. Not 1 and 3 as expected

Comment: @starbyone . . . If fixed the `join` condition.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - This works perfectly. I added a group by and concatenated the v.col to get the list of missing fields. I did have a view bit columns and int columns but just CAST them to VARCHAR. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care which columns are not filled in, you can use the following solution which does not use any Dynamic SQL. Just replace TableA and TableB with your own tables. You might have to put TableB in a subquery to convert columns into other datatypes if the unpivot complains. You would have to add any columns to the unpivot as you expand the table structure. For this example I will assume all your data columns are varchar(50).

The query unpivots the second table, and compares counts of fields provided against fields required.

```
;WITH TableBProvided AS
(
SELECT ContactId, ContactTypeID, COUNT(ContactTypeId) as FieldsProvided, STRING_AGG(ColumnName,', ') As ColumnNamesProvided 
FROM TableB
UNPIVOT  
   (ColumnValue FOR ColumnName in
      (FirstName, LastName, HomePhone, [Address], Email)  
) AS unpvt
GROUP BY ContactId, ContactTypeID
)
,TableARequired AS
(
SELECT ContactTypeId, Count(FieldId) as RequiredFieldCount, STRING_AGG(ColumnName,', ') As ColumnNamesRequired 
FROM TableA
GROUP BY ContactTypeId
)
SELECT ContactId, FieldsProvided, RequiredFieldCount, ColumnNamesProvided, ColumnNamesRequired FROM TableBProvided TBP
JOIN TableARequired TAR ON TAR.ContactTypeId = TBP.ContactTypeId
WHERE RequiredFieldCount <> FieldsProvided
```

If you want to specifically get the fields missing you would have to perform something called relational division if I remember correctly, which is a bit over my head.

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Answer (score 0):

This could be done without dynamic SQL, but it would have to be hardcoded.

Everytime, when you store somewhere column names and want to do logic based on that, most probably it will lead you to dynamic SQL sooner or later.

Moreover, it doesn't have to be not efficient, as querying table with required fields won't take long, as (I guess) it won't be big and after isnpecting your produced dynamic SQL, you can create proper indexes to reduce the querying of the other table (for example `ContactTypeId` is good candidate for index).

Having said that, here's approach using dynamic SQL (note `string_agg` function, which is available in new SQL Servers, for old ones you need to apply other approach, which can be found easily on this site, I used `string_agg` for brevity):

```
create table TestTable (ContactID int, ContactTypeID int, FirstName varchar(30), LastName varchar(30), HomePhone varchar(30), Address varchar(30), Email varchar(30));
insert into TestTable values
(1 , 1 ,'Mary' ,'Smith', Null ,Null , Null),
(2 , 1 ,'Jim' ,'Smith', '999-999-9999' ,Null , Null),
(3 , 2 ,'Steve' ,'Jones', Null ,Null , Null);
create table RequiredInfo (ContactTypeID int, FieldID int, ColumnName varchar(30), FieldName varchar(30));
insert into RequiredInfo values
(1, 1, 'FirstName', 'First Name'),
(1, 2, 'LastName', 'Last Name'),
(1, 3, 'HomePhone', 'Home Phone'),
(2, 1, 'FirstName', 'First Name'),
(2, 2, 'LastName', 'Last Name'),
(2, 3, 'HomePhone', 'Home Phone'),
(2, 4, 'Address', 'Home Address'),
(2, 5, 'Email', 'Email Address');

declare @sql as varchar(1000) = 'select * from TestTable where ';
select @sql = @sql + string_agg(clauses, ' or ') from (
    select '( ContactTypeId = ' + cast(ContactTypeId as varchar(10)) + ' and (' +
           string_agg( ColumnName + ' is null', ' or ' ) + ') )' clauses
    from RequiredInfo
    group by contacttypeid
) a

exec (@sql)
```